# How should I modify this code to accomodate async behaviour?

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

I have a button. If the button is pressed I want all buttons to be disabled. Then I want something done. After that something is done, I want all buttons to be re-enabled.

Simple right?

Here is the code

```
Public Sub startAndStopClickingButton(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal SomeSub As System.Action)
    startClickingButton(sender)
    SomeSub.Invoke()
    stopClickingButton(sender)
End Sub
```

I then do

```
Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdGroupRepeat.Click
    startAndStopClickingButton(sender, Sub()
                                           finRepeatOrdering() ' this one never end
                                           Dim b = 1
                                       End Sub)
End Sub
```

It worked fine. Startclickingbutton is called. Then I invoke whatever lambda is in the middle. Then after it finished (it never is actually), stopclickingbutton is called. Simple.

Then I changed my program. finRepeatOrdering is now finRepeatOrderingAsync.

However, I still want the same behavior. I want await finRepeatOrderingAsync to finish before stopClickingButton is pressed.

So, I did this

```
Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdGroupRepeat.Click
    startAndStopClickingButton(sender, Async Sub()
                                           Await finRepeatOrderingAsync() ' this one never end
                                           Dim b = 1 'a breakpoint here
                                       End Sub)
End Sub
```

Now that dim b=1 is never called. However, stopClickingButton is called prematurely. How come?

And how should I change the program to make this work?

I tried

```
Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdGroupRepeat.Click
    startAndStopClickingButton(sender, Async Function() As Task
                                           Await finRepeatOrderingAsync() ' this one never end
                                           Dim b = 1
                                       End Function)
End Sub

Public Async Function startAndStopClickingButton2(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal SomeSub As System.Func(Of Task)) As Task
    startClickingButton(sender)
    Await SomeSub.Invoke()
    stopClickingButton(sender)
End Function
```

And I got a compiler warning

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning BC42359 The Task returned from this Async Function will be dropped, and any exceptions in it ignored. Consider changing it to an Async Sub so its exceptions are propagated.    nicehash2   H:\business\shared\Dropbox\vb.net\nicehashform.vb   60  Active

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Public Async Function startAndStopClickingButton(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal SomeSub As System.Func(Of Task)) As Task
    startClickingButton(sender)
    Await SomeSub.Invoke()
    stopClickingButton(sender)
End Function

Private Async Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdGroupRepeat.Click
    Await startAndStopClickingButton(sender, Async Function() As Task
                                           Await finRepeatOrderingAsync()
                                           Dim b = 1
                                       End Sub)
End Sub
```

Comment: I got a compiler warning.

Comment: What compiler warning?

Comment: I forget. But think about it. startAndStopClickingButton is an async function that returns task. It should be awaited right? But no. You just call an async function without await.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using invoke but not Task.run? You could try;

```
Public Async Sub startAndStopClickingButton(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal SomeSub As System.Action)
    startClickingButton(sender)
    Await Task.Run(SomeSub) 
    stopClickingButton(sender)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code did it

```
Private Async Sub RepeatTheWholeThing_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdGroupRepeat.Click
    Await startAndStopClickingButton2(sender, Async Function() As Task
                                                  Await finRepeatOrderingAsync() ' this one never end
                                                  Dim b = 1
                                              End Function)
End Sub

Public Async Function startAndStopClickingButton2(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal SomeSub As System.Func(Of Task)) As Task
    startClickingButton(sender)
    Await SomeSub.Invoke()
    stopClickingButton(sender)
End Function
```

The handler itself need to be async. Then the startAndStopClickingButton need to be an async too. The only difference with Paulo's answer is that I await startAndStopClickingButton2.

To see how this works we need to see that await doesn't really block. It returns to the caller. After `Await SomeSub.Invoke()` is done, an event handler will run and execute stopClickingButton(sender)

If there is a better solution. I wonder if the handler has to be async or whether startAndStopClickingButton really need to be changed. If so, why? That would be another question.